# Rails - Conditional Routes - Multiple Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, routes, conditional-statements, submit

I am not sure if this is possible in Rails, but I have an order form where I would like to allow updates to certain fields based on the status of the order.  I can manage this with the form_for and the appropriate logic in the controller and such.

However on the same form I would like to have a button which allows the user to pay (via stripe checkout) if the order is complete.

Essentially this "Pay" button should post to a different route  (Payments) than the Order

Is there a way to define the 2nd submit button so it posts to a different route?

Comment: Show what you've done so far. controller/views/etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Comment: I wanted 2 forms such as <%= form_for @order, :url => url_for(:controller => 'orders', :action => 'update1') do |f| %>